# .value_counts() on a series returns series is already the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

new to pandas (love that it's required to preface with that)
I ran a groupby on a dataframe to create a new df, state_groups. Now I want to make a series that shows the number of values in each state, but when I run value_counts using the right syntax, I get the index (State Abbreviation) then the series I grouped by (STABBR (same as index) and then the value counts.

```
state_counts = state_groups['STABBR'].value_counts()
```

output:

```
STABBR  STABBR
AK      AK         3
AL      AL        14
AR      AR        10
AZ      AZ         8
CA      CA        32
```

How do I yield just the index and count? Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you need to do it in two parts or can you add the count aggregate to your groupby in the first place?

Comment: Good question. I tried that as well.   ```state_counts = df_undergrad.groupby('STABBR')['STABBR'].value_counts()``` and got the same output.